# Ng-Model Over-writing any Values that I put in the Input field in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Angular ng-model is overwriting any value or expression that i put in an input or textarea value field. If I remove the ng-model everything works normally but as soon as I add ng-model it makes the field empty.. I tried populating the ng-model using some values from the controller but it doesn't works..

```
<input type="text" ng-model="note.title" value="{{title}}">
<textarea ng-model="note.notes">{{notes}}</textarea>
```

Though the expression value is rendered correctly in the Elements Inspector and is present but the View shows blank form if the model is present else it shows the right value.

Comment: Great. Can you show some working code that replicates the issue?

Comment: This is how Angular works. The form values are bound to a javascript controller using `ng-model`, not the `value` attribute. Are you just trying to set an initial value for these fields?

Comment: Try by removing {{notes}} and {{title}} but remaining ng-models.

Answer (score 0):

**HTML Replicated Code**

```
<form action="update.php" ng-controller="EditController" method="post" id="UpdateForm">
    <input type="text" value="{{title}}">
    <textarea>{{notes}}</textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

**Javascript Code**

```
var notesId = $routeParams.notesId;

$scope.editNotes = function() {
    $http.post('www/edit.php', notesId)
        .success(function(data) {
            $scope.allNotes = data;
            //here i updated value
            $scope.notes = $scope.allNotes[0].text_notes; 
            $scope.title = $scope.allNotes[0].notes_title;
        });
};

$scope.editNotes();
```

The values of `$scope.notes` & `$scope.title` is what I want to display in the Form field values, because I'm updating some stuff & I don't want my users to start from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a [sample JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lcc758mm/2/) using your code as a base and expanding on it. Hope this helps. You'll notice that I added the "error" handler just because I don't have the service you're using available. You can replicate that same logic to your "success" function so the form gets updated once you have a successful response from the service.

Basically, sample HTML:

```
<div ng-app>
    <form action="update.php" ng-controller="EditController" method="post" id="UpdateForm">
        <input type="text" ng-model="notes.title" value="{{title}}">
        <textarea ng-model="notes.notes">{{notes}}</textarea>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
</div>
```

and sample JavaScript:

```
function EditController($scope, $http){
    var notesId = 5;

    $scope.editNotes = function () {
        $http.post('www/edit.php',notesId)
            .success(function(data){
                $scope.allNotes = data;
                $scope.notes = $scope.allNotes[0].notes_title;
                $scope.title = $scope.allNotes[0].notes_title;

            })
            .error(function(data){
                $scope.notes = {title: "title", notes: "notes"};

            })

    };

    $scope.editNotes();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to specify value attribute when you are using ng-model. Simply assign the value to variable you are specifying in ng-model and it will automatically populate the input fields.

Try this:

```
<form action="update.php" ng-controller="EditController" method="post" id="UpdateForm">
    <input type="text" data-ng-model="title" />
    <textarea data-ng-model="notes"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

I noticed in your code you are using it with "notes." but you havent specified controller alias if you want to use in this way try this:

```
<form action="update.php" ng-controller="EditController as notes" method="post" id="UpdateForm">
        <input type="text" data-ng-model="notes.title" />
        <textarea data-ng-model="notes.notes"></textarea>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
```